# I read a book, back when I was in high school. But I can’t remember the title or the author. Please help?

Tags: story-identification

I read this book back in year 10, about a guy who dies and end up in a form of after life, where there is some form of contest that apparently no one has ever won before. However he wins and is brought back to life. I could be wrong but I think that is how it goes. But I can remember the title of the book, nor can I remember the author. So hopefully someone out there can help me find it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Please, at least, tell us when you were in high school. Surprisingly, some of us may not know.

Comment: i have removed the year range. i don't see where Caseyanne claims to be user95108 or a comment indicating the year range. also *"back in year 10"* implies a school year level which is one year, not a range of 4 years